# Date expression in Oracle

Tags: oracle

How will the following expression be evaluated to in Oracle?

```
WHERE nvl(MODIFIEDDATE, TO_DATE('2030/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'))
  > TO_DATE('', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Can anyone explain what this would do? I am not Oracle person.

Comment: It won't match anything; you really have an empty string (null) in the second `to_date()` call? That will evaluate to null, and nothing can be compared with that...

Comment: So this WHERE clause will do nothing?

Comment: Exactly, you asked it to do nothing(NULL), it does nothing.

Comment: Will it exclude records where Date is NULL?

Comment: A query which includes the above comparison will return nothing. So I suppose you could say it will exclude records where Date is NULL - but will exclude everything else as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's walk through this in detail:

```
NVL(MODIFIEDDATE, TO_DATE('2030/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

This will return `MODIFIEDDATE` if it is not NULL. If `MODIFIEDDATE` is NULL then it will return a `DATE` value of `2030/01/01 00:00:00` (the time component will default to midnight because it's not specified in the time literal of '2030/01/01'). So this will always return a non-NULL DATE value.

`TO_DATE('', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')`

This will always return NULL. A zero-length string, in Oracle, means `NULL`. This is by design (it goes back to the very earliest days of Oracle), and is IMO one of the *worst* design decisions in the Oracle product. But it's what it is - a zero-length string in Oracle is NULL, always and forever. And NULLs are poison, so `TO_DATE(NULL, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')` will return NULL.

So now we've got

```
SOME_VALID_DATE_VALUE > NULL
```

This will always return NULL, because any comparison with NULL returns NULL (remember - NULLs are poison). So the WHERE clause becomes

```
WHERE NULL...
```

And thus the query which uses this WHERE clause will return no rows.

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a date with NULL.

This:

> nvl(MODIFIEDDATE, TO_DATE('2030/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'))

Means, whenever `MODIFIEDDATE` is NULL, use the date value instead.

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS';

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT TO_DATE('2030/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') LHS, TO_DATE('', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') RHS FROM dual;

LHS                 RHS
------------------- -------------------
2030/01/01 00:00:00

SQL>
```

So, basically, comparing anything with NULL will result is...."unknown". Therefore, your query would return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The first half of the condition:

```
nvl(MODIFIEDDATE, TO_DATE('2030/01/01', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'))
```

... means that if the `MODIFIEDDATE` column is null, a magic date of 2030-01-01 will be used instead.

The second half of the condition:

```
TO_DATE('', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

... will always evaluate to null. Null cannot be compared to any other value including itself, except with the `is [not] null` operator.

The result of this condition will always be 'unknown', so no rows will be returned.

It will exclude all rows, not just those that have a null date; the `nvl()` means that any null values are given a dummy value anyway. If you only wanted to exclude those with a null date you could specify `WHERE MODIFIEDDATE IS NOT NULL`, but it isn't really clear that's what is intended by that code.